# Product slider issue in owl carousal in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2

I am facing issue in owl carousal below one is the code, but it showing error,

```
<script>
            require([
                'jquery',
                'Mageplaza_Productslider/js/owl.carousel.min'
            ], function ($) {
                $('#mageplaza-product-slider-<?php echo $productsliderId;?>').owlCarousel(<?php echo ($block->getAllOptions())?>);
            });
    </script>




Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at /pub/static/version1514191789/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Mageplaza_Productslider/js/owl.carousel.min.js:6
    at /pub/static/version1514191789/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Mageplaza_Productslider/js/owl.carousel.min.js:6
(index):890 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function
    at (index):890
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
    at Module.check (require.js:866)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113)
    at require.js:132
    at require.js:1156
    at each (require.js:57)
    at Module.emit (require.js:1155)
    at Module.check (require.js:917)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1143)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `app/code/Mageplaza/Productslider/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
         'Owlcarousel' : 'Mageplaza_Productslider/js/owl.carousel.min'     
      },   
    shim: {
        'Owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
}
```

Script for phtml:

```
<script>
     require([
          'jquery',
          'Owlcarousel'
     ], function ($, Owlcarousel) {
      $('#mageplaza-product-slider-<?php echo $productsliderId;?>').owlCarousel(<?php echo ($block->getAllOptions())?>);
     });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak for your comment few mins 'll try and let you know

Comment: Same issue Ronak any other solution?

Comment: paste your requirejs code  in question

Comment: var config = {
    map: {
        '*' : {
            'Mageplaza_Productslider/js/owl.carousel' : 'Mageplaza_Productslider/js/owl.carousel',
            'Mageplaza_Productslider/js/owl.carousel.min' : 'Mageplaza_Productslider/js/owl.carousel.min'
        }
    }
};

Comment: any idea ronak?

Comment: check my updated ans.

Comment: Do I need to run comment after adding this? I got 404 /pub/static/version1514191789/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Owlcarousel.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: run command :  `php bin/magneto setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`